# What's the meaning of 上 in this sentence?

Tags: words

I am not sure what 上 means in this sentence. I know that 上 means `above` or `on`, but I think the meaning here is different because it does not mention anything above or on the sushi.

> 僕はいつもここでは握り寿司の**上**を頼むんだ。

Does it mean:

> I always ask for the top hand-rolled sushi here.

i.e. best hand-rolled sushi?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, 上 in a restaurant menu is read じょう, and it means "deluxe", "premium" or "high grade". But 上 is often not the highest ranked menu, because restaurants commonly offer 特上 menus, too.

> 特上【とくじょう】 (lit. super deluxe)　＞　上【じょう】　(lit. deluxe) ＞　並【なみ】 (lit. normal)

So practically, 上 is often considered as "middle grade".

Another traditional way to express the rank of food is 松【まつ】 ＞ 竹【たけ】 ＞ 梅【うめ】, which are frequently used in *bento* shops, *sushi* restaurants and *unagi* restaurants.

Reference:

- [松竹梅のランクの意味](http://xn--p9jbr9b1a6d5316g.com/archives/401.html)