# Meaning of idioms difficult to translate

Tags: meaning, phrases

I have to understand two japanese idioms and I am having a very hard time finding a meaning for them (on a dictionary I mean). Can someone explain them to me

1. 机上　as in 「机上実行」 related to the execution of a program in ***not*** the actual environment.
   I mean there are two modes of execution it seems. The first one (実機）and the second one (机上）　So what is the translation of that?
2. 松竹梅案の比較 what does that mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

机上実行 is not a common phrase, but it probably refers to simulating each step of a program in one's brain or using the code printed on paper (e.g., to find the cause of a difficult logical bug, to check a software design). There is an idiom [机上の空論](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9C%BA%E4%B8%8A%E3%81%AE%E7%A9%BA%E8%AB%96). By extension, 机上【きじょう】 or 机の上 by itself sometimes carries a nuance of "(optimistic) simulation/theory". A possible translation would be "brain execution" or "paper simulation", but what it actually refers to should depend on the context or your workplace.

[松竹梅【しょうちくばい】](https://jisho.org/search/%E6%9D%BE%E7%AB%B9%E6%A2%85) is a traditional way of grading something (see [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/33653/5010)). 松竹梅案 is a humorous way of referring to three plans (案) with different prices or grades. 松(案) is the deluxe plan, and 梅(案) is the cheapest.